# Visual studio show docs when pressing ctrl+space

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xml-documentation

For some reason I can see docs only for .net libraries. Is there a way to see my own or third party docs in Visual studio?

I would like to know if its possible to see docs when pressing ctrl+space in Visual Studio 2010. Similar to what I'm used to in Eclipse :). Or at least when clicking (selecting) on method or class to be able to see docs in some kind of view (window)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "docs" I assume you mean Intellisense tooltip? This tooltip will include XML documentation if that exists for the method. [XML documentation in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04awywx.aspx) is described on MSDN. To add summary documentation to a method you add a special comment prefixed by `///`:

```
public class Foo {

  /// <summary>
  ///   Bars the foo.
  /// </summary>
  public void Bar() {
  }

}
```

In VB.Net you can use the the same XML but will have to use `'''` instead of `///` as the special comment character.

You will have to compile the assembly using the `/doc` option. You can enable it in the project properties:

[image: Enabling generation of XML documentation in project properties]

The generated XML file should follow the assembly if you copy it to another location.

Answer (score 4):

1. Generate XML documentation by enabling the appropriate option in project's properties (Build tab)
2. Put resulting XML file in the same folder as the DLL